# Devel dpq() not working?

Tags: 7, debugging

I am trying to print the sql generated from the view but its not working. Below is the error message I am getting:-

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function arguments() on a non-object in /var/www/Exaxmple-Site/sites/all/modules/devel/devel.module on line 1834
```

I have seen many of them using this function to print the sql statement but in my case its giving error. Below is the code how I am calling the function.

```
function example_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
    if ($view->name == 'search_jobs'){

        dpq($view->build_info['query']); 
    }
}
```

Has anyone experienced this issue before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want show sql query you can use code below:

```
function example_views_pre_execute(&$view) {
  if ($view->name == 'search_jobs'){
        dpq($view->build_info['query']); 
    }
}
```

In your code function dpq error because variable $view->build_info['query'] is **NULL**. The function dpq only run when variable is **An object that implements the SelectQueryInterface interface**.